# Throw error message doesn't compile on OOP Javascript ternary operators

Tags: javascript, oop, conditional-operator, throw

Why does this way it compiles:

```
this.setAlunos = function(alunos){
    if(this.getTurma() > 0){
        this.alunos = alunos.split(",");
    }
    else{
        throw "you must set a 'turma' before inserting students on it";
    }
};
```

And this does not?

```
this.setAlunos = function(alunos){
    this.getTurma() > 0 ? this.alunos = alunos.split(",") : throw "you must set a 'turma' before inserting students on it";
};
```

Comment: `throw` is a statement like `var` etc.. you cannot use statements in expressions. This is what we get when people say `? :` is "same as if else". :X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually throw an error directly inside a ternary operator, like you're trying to do there. You can, however, wrap the `throw` in an anonymous function, like this:

```
this.setAlunos = function(alunos){
    this.getTurma() > 0 ? this.alunos = alunos.split(",") : (function(){throw "you must set a 'turma' before inserting students on it"}());
};
```

Then it will work properly. However, just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*. I recommend leaving your code as it was before, as it's much more readable.

Comment: Why is this applied for ternary operator only?

Comment: Like Esailija said, the ternary operator is an expression, and you can't use statements in expressions.